# Memory data layout vs algorithm performance

Tags: performance, algorithm, memory, low-latency

How layout of a data in memory effects on algorithm performance?
For example merge sort is know for it computational complexity of O(n log n).
But in real world machine that processing algorithm will load/unload blocks of memory into CPU caches / CPU registers and spend auxiliary time on it.
Elements of collection to be sorted could be very scattered throughout the memory, and I wonder it will cause in slower performance vs sorting over gathered together elements.

Is in necessary to take into account how collections are really stores the data in memory?

Comment: Yes, especially for large data (that does not even fit in RAM) this is crucial, because the paging hit is huge. There are specific fields of research trying to exploit locality properties of the data, such that substeps of the algorithm can be performed on a block of data that fits in memory. I know this field as IO-efficient algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

1. In terms of big O notation - no. The time you read each block from
   RAM to cpu cache is bounded by some constant, let it be `C`, so even
   if you need to load each element in every iteration from RAM to
   cache, you are going to need `O(C*nlogn)` time, but since `C` is
   constant - it remains `O(nlogn)` time complexity.
2. In real world applications, especially when dealing with real-time apps, cache performance could be indeed a factor, and should be considered, so the order of accessing data, could matter. This is one of the reasons why quicksort is usually regarded as "faster" - it tends to have nice cache performance.

   In addition - there are some algorithms that are developed to enjoy the "best of two worlds" - both `O(nlogn)` worst case with better constants, such as [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

However, as rule of thumb, you should usually first implement the "easy way", then benchmark to see if it's fast enough, profile if it's not - and optimize the bottleneck. If you'll try to optimize every piece of your code for best cache performance - you will probably never finish writing it.

Comment: The claim (1) that RAM access is O(1) is questionable. It's at best O(n^0.333) since there's only O(d^3) of RAM that can be within distance d of the CPU.

Comment: @Anonymous we regard RAM as "Random Access Memory", even though it's not true anymore, in most literature (of software) I'm aware of, each cache fill is regarded as taking a bounded time, and micro-optimization of cache fills (that I'm aware of) try to minimize number of cache fills, regardless of the block being queried (with exception of favoring better tier cache: L1<L2<L3<RAM<disk)

Answer (score 1):

Profiling, profiling, profiling.

Modern computer architectures have become so complicated that accurate predictions on the running time have become impossible. You should prefer an experimental approach.

Also note that running times are no more deterministic and you should resort to statistical methods.

Architecture killed the algorithmician.

Answer (score 0):

> How layout of a data in memory effects on algorithm performance?

Layout is very important especially for large amount of data because access to the main memory is still expensive even for modern CPU:
http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.ru/2013/02/cpu-cache-flushing-fallacy.html

And your algo may spend much time on each cache miss:
http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.ru/2012/08/memory-access-patterns-are-important.html

Moreover, now there is a special area in Computer Science called Cache-friendly data structures and algos. See, for example, just googled:
http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~bader/COURSES/UNM/ece637-Fall2003/papers/LFN02.pdf
etc etc